# If, Elif and Else not display correct print values in Profit Calculator App

Tags: python

I'm new here at StackOverflow but I've been "messing around with" HTML and CSS since the age of 8. I recently picked up a course on Python (at 25) and decided to use programming as an expansion of my career path. I'm working on a small program that allows me and fellow Shopify eCommerce owners (in Brazil where I currently live) to calculate the profit margin of a single product, using user input (product retail price, product cost, cpa) . It's also supposed to display the profit margins depending on the amount of times a store/vendor finances the product without interest (parcelas). There is some kind of issue where the program only ever displays the profit margin for a 1 time payment. I've been at this for hours and tried Googling but can't seem to find a specific issue that would tie in with mine. My last resort is to ask you guys for help before I go absolutely insane lool. The program displays in portuguese but all the variables are assigned in English. If you need any help comprehending the code, please do let me know! I have tried to make it as comprehensible as possible.

```
#Product Retail Price
product_retail_price = float(input("Valor do produto na loja em Reais (Formato 00.00): "))

#Costs
product_cost = float(input("Valor do produto no fornecedor em Reais (Formato 00.00): "))
cpa = float(input("Custo por aquisição (Formato 00.00): "))
fee_shopify = (product_retail_price / 100)*2
fee_mercadopago = (product_retail_price / 100)*4.99
fee_finance_2 = (product_retail_price / 100)*2.03
fee_finance_3 = (product_retail_price / 100)*4.06
fee_finance_4 = (product_retail_price / 100)*6.09
fee_finance_5 = (product_retail_price / 100)*7.64
fee_finance_6 = (product_retail_price / 100)*8.92
fee_finance_7 = (product_retail_price / 100)*10.06
fee_finance_8 = (product_retail_price / 100)*10.62
fee_finance_9 = (product_retail_price / 100)*11.23
fee_finance_10 = (product_retail_price / 100)*12.41
fee_finance_11 = (product_retail_price / 100)*13.60
fee_finance_12 = (product_retail_price / 100)*14.80
fee_finance_15 = (product_retail_price / 100)*18.47
fee_finance_18 = (product_retail_price / 100)*22.23
fee_finance_24 = (product_retail_price / 100)*23.83

#Calculations
parcelas = int(input("Número de parcelas sem juros (Formato: 0-24): "))
base_profit = round(product_retail_price - product_cost - fee_shopify - fee_mercadopago - cpa, 2)
profit_2 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_2 - cpa, 2)
profit_3 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_3 - cpa, 2)
profit_4 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_4 - cpa, 2)
profit_5 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_5 - cpa, 2)
profit_6 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_6 - cpa, 2)
profit_7 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_7 - cpa, 2)
profit_8 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_8 - cpa, 2)
profit_9 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_9 - cpa, 2)
profit_10 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_10 - cpa, 2)
profit_11 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_11 - cpa, 2)
profit_12 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_12 - cpa, 2)
profit_15 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_15 - cpa, 2)
profit_18 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_18 - cpa, 2)
profit_24 = round(base_profit - fee_finance_24 - cpa, 2)

#Print Values
print("\n")

if parcelas == 0 or 1:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
elif parcelas == 2:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
elif parcelas == 3:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
elif parcelas == 4:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
elif parcelas == 5:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
elif parcelas == 6:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
elif parcelas == 7:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
elif parcelas == 8:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
elif parcelas == 9:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}")
elif parcelas == 10:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 10x: R${profit_10}")
elif parcelas == 11:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 10x: R${profit_10}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 11x: R${profit_11}")
elif parcelas == 12 or 13 or 14:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 10x: R${profit_10}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 11x: R${profit_11}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 12x: R${profit_12}")
elif parcelas == 15 or 18 or 17:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 10x: R${profit_10}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 11x: R${profit_11}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 12x: R${profit_12}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 15x: R${profit_15}")
elif parcelas == 18 or 19 or 20 or 21 or 22 or 23:
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 10x: R${profit_10}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 11x: R${profit_11}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 12x: R${profit_12}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 15x: R${profit_15}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 18x: R${profit_18}")
else: 
    print(f"Lucro à vista: R${base_profit}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 10x: R${profit_10}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 11x: R${profit_11}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 12x: R${profit_12}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 15x: R${profit_15}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 18x: R${profit_18}")
    print(f"Lucro parcelado 24x: R${profit_24}")
print("\n")
print("AVISO: Lucro calculado usando as taxas atuais do MercadoPago (23/07/2018)")
```

Comment: After this works, I think it would be a disservice to leave you believing that this is well written, or that any of our suggestions in the answers are good advice on how to clearly and neatly express this logic. The answers are basically the minimal changes to fix your current problem. If you'd like some discussion of alternative ways to write this consider taking it to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and asking there, there will probably be many insights for you to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider make

```
elif parcelas == 12 or 13 or 14:
```

to

```
elif parcelas in [12,13,14]:
```

and etc.

Because `parcelas == 12 or 13 or 14:` will always return True, it will evaluate like `parcelas==12` or `13` or `14`, which is definitely True and ignore the following statement.

Create list for print statement:

```
>>> lst=[]
>>> for i in range(2,24):
        lst.append("Lucro parcelado "+str(i)+"x: R${profit_"+str(i)+"}")


>>> lst
['Lucro parcelado 2x: R${profit_2}', 'Lucro parcelado 3x: R${profit_3}', 'Lucro parcelado 4x: R${profit_4}', 'Lucro parcelado 5x: R${profit_5}', 'Lucro parcelado 6x: R${profit_6}', 'Lucro parcelado 7x: R${profit_7}', 'Lucro parcelado 8x: R${profit_8}', 'Lucro parcelado 9x: R${profit_9}', 'Lucro parcelado 10x: R${profit_10}', 'Lucro parcelado 11x: R${profit_11}', 'Lucro parcelado 12x: R${profit_12}', 'Lucro parcelado 13x: R${profit_13}', 'Lucro parcelado 14x: R${profit_14}', 'Lucro parcelado 15x: R${profit_15}', 'Lucro parcelado 16x: R${profit_16}', 'Lucro parcelado 17x: R${profit_17}', 'Lucro parcelado 18x: R${profit_18}', 'Lucro parcelado 19x: R${profit_19}', 'Lucro parcelado 20x: R${profit_20}', 'Lucro parcelado 21x: R${profit_21}', 'Lucro parcelado 22x: R${profit_22}', 'Lucro parcelado 23x: R${profit_23}']
>>>
```

Comment: That would make things neater! Is there to not have to copy and neaten all those print statements? As you can see currently they're all duplicated with an addition of the last value.

Comment: Definitely can. You can make it into a list can call from list with index, check the updated answer.

Comment: Looks great. There is just one issue I have. The increments only follow a pattern up to a certain number. The amount of times the product can be financed is as follows:

0 (one time payment), 2-12, 15, 18, 24

What currently happens is that if someone types in 1 it shows them 0. If they type in 16-17 it shows them 15, if they type 19-23 it shows them 18.

How would I tackle this in that case? I basically need to skip some items in the list.

Comment: Not sure which line you are referring to. But you can make if it is greater than 1: make the value plus one.

Comment: If you look at the profit variables, there are a few jumps. They don't all follow increments of 1 (2-24). The items can be financed in 2-12 times, 15, 18 or 24 times. What I'm currently doing is basically letting the person type in the numbers 13,14,16,17,19-23 and it only shows the true number of times the product can be financed. If I was to generate a range from 2 to 24 some of the parts of the list wouldn't correspond the actual number of times in which a product can be financed paste.ofcode.org/QhJEU4buJU74Dx5pLrP6RX

Comment: for a number greater than 12. I guess you have to loop 1 from 12 then manually add in15,18,24. There are ways using a list to automate this, but the setup time is not worth taking rather than just manually put in 15,18,24,etc..

Comment: I will dwell on that for a bit tomorrow and see what I can work out! I'd like to eventually give it a UI and make it into a .exe. Thank you :D

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helps you. It will remove this from the review queue and save other editors' time.

Comment: Still haven't been able to make sense of it. I've been at this for the last 4 hours and still haven't managed to squeeze the text. I've created a while loop that doesn't let the user input the wrong amount of installments but that's all so far. I've been trying to make dictionaries and lists that would do part of the calc and print the final statements but no luck. I also posted on CodeReview but :((

Comment: What’s the main obstacle now? You can create new question on your challenge, but make sure it is minimal concise. Also, making apps is not just about algorithms, it requires much more effort.

Comment: I'm trying to cut the code down in order to minimize the amount of repetition. I was given an answer but unfortunately it came back with a few errors that I can't figure out how to fix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508104/create-variables-using-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 2):

statements like

```
elif parcelas == 15 or 18 or 17:
```

will not work. You need to do something like:

```
elif parcelas == 15 or parcelas == 18 or parcelas == 17:
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
if parcelas == 0 or 1:
```

There are two separate conditions being evaluated `parcelas == 0`, and `1`. Because `1` will be evaluated as true, this statement will always be entered. You need to ensure to compare with every value you want to - `parcelas == 0 or parcelas == 1`

There are other lines with similar issues.

There are other ways to write this that will be neater, but I'm not familiar enough with python to know the syntax for those. If you just care about a range, rather than a list of discrete values, then consider using something like `parcelas >= 0 and parcelas < 2` for these conditions.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I didn't think of that at all! Thank you so much! :) I'm still a beginner, I still have some issues with flow and logic. Can anyone give me a hand with making this neater?